# Selenium phpunit testing without DB

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

**Intro:**
I have a Yii webapp which I want to test using phpunit and selenium testing, but here is the catch, I do not use a DB. I communicate with an API which integrates with Yii's activeRecord (https://github.com/Haensel/ActiveResource).

**Situation:**
So I have phpunit test working and I have a running Selenium stand alone server running as well. I do not use the FF plugin. I run it as a unit test:

```
<?php 
class TestTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public $fixtures=array(
        //'posts'=>'Post',
    );

    public function testShow()
    {
        $this->open('site/login');
        // verify the sample post title exists
        $this->assertTextPresent($this->posts['sample1']['title']);
        // verify comment form exists
        $this->assertTextPresent('Password');
    }
}
?>
```

But it keeps trying to connect to the database, which doesn't exist. My webapp works fine without the database connection so I know it doesn't need it.

**Question:**

So what I want to know is whether it is actually possible (I am new to Yii, but lots of MVC experience)?

How can I "set it up" to not look for a DB resource?

Has anyone done this and maybe have a few pointers or guide etc?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can I "set it up" to not look for a DB resource" -> I believe that you can do that in the same file "protected/config/main.php", that you set it up to look for a DB.

Comment: Nope removed all db sources from all my configs and it still requests one, in the end I actually just created a db for it... even though it does nothing

Comment: Hum. If you removed all, i believe, it will request for one. Try just use the default config of main.php.